# Running unit test on Spring Boot Application from Gitlab CI

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a spring boot application with maven for dependency management. I have pushed this application to Gitlab and would like to use its CI/CD feature. I created a file .gitlab-ci.yml and added the following:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:


- build
  - package
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package"
```

I have taken this code snippet from [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@deeksha.sharma25/spring-boot-micro-service-with-gitlab-ci-281c6679b3f8).

Now on every push to the repository, the job runs but the test cases fail. I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateFromString » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContex...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeAnually » IllegalState Fail...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeCurrentMonth » IllegalState
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeCurrentQuarter » IllegalState
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeCurrentWeek » IllegalState ...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeCurrentYear » IllegalState ...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeDaily » IllegalState Failed...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeMonthly » IllegalState Fail...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeQuarterly » IllegalState Fa...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeSemiAnually » IllegalState ...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeSemiMonthly » IllegalState ...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeWeekly » IllegalState Faile...
[ERROR]   DateUtilTest.getNearestFutureDateFromCurrentDate » IllegalState Failed to load...
```

I am not sure how to solve this `IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext` error or why it occurs.

My sample test case looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public final class DateUtilTest {

    private Calendar calendar;

    private Date date;

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2019, 1, 11, 10, 0, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        date = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.set(2019, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        startDate = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.set(2019, 1, 11, 23, 59, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
        endDate = calendar.getTime();
    }

    @Test
    public void getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalTypeDaily() {
        DateInterval dateInterval = DateUtil.getDateIntervalFromDateAndIntervalType(IntervalType.DAILY, date);
        assertEquals(startDate, dateInterval.getStartDate());
        assertEquals(endDate, dateInterval.getEndDate());
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong/missing with the test case or the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: Longshot, but I too have come across this problem - did you manage to find anything in the end? :-)